# Why is Jeff Atwood's reputation so high on meta?

Tags: discussion, reputation, jeff-atwood

Why do you think Jeff Atwood's reputation points on meta has reached 7,733 in just 37 days, while on Stack Overflow it's only 14,371 after a year?

Comment: Waiting for him to answer in this question so I can down him one.

Comment: What would it matter? He is Jeff...the Jeff.

Comment: Shouldn't this be on meta-meta-SO?

Comment: Politics man, it's all politics. :)

Comment: Update table users set reputation = 7733 where id = 1  (additional queries omitted for clarity)

Comment: Everyone knows, Jeff just *lives* for "meta"! (Big wink)

Answer (score 32, accepted):

On Stack Overflow, he is just a well-known user of above-average skills.

To paraphrase *[The Matrix Revolutions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Matrix_Revolutions)*:

> Down here, he's god.

Basically, he runs the site, and I'd say a lot of people +rep him by default when he posts.

Comment: +1 for the Matrix Revolutions quote (which was an awful movie IMO).

Answer (score 49):

He's the authority on MSO. Every answer he gives is *the* answer.

Comment: the ultimate answer

Comment: Shouldn't this be obvious?

Comment: When someone asks him if he's a god, he says, _"YES!"_

Comment: @Joel Coehoorn: It was Linus Torvalds - "My name is Linus Torvalds and I am your god." - Linus Torvalds, 1998

Comment: I was thinking more Winston Zeddemore, 1984: http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0087332/quotes

Comment: Excuse me?! What happened to [Jon Skeet](https://stackoverflow.com/users/22656/jon-skeet)?!?!

Answer (score 15):

I heard he has root on the box and will fiddle with the database sometimes.

Comment: Actually it's running on Windows, so it would be Administrator instead of root.

Comment: I know ;) But I thought everyone renamed their Administrator account to root on Windows!  http://support.microsoft.com/kb/816109

Answer (score 14):

Obviously, he's more active on this site than SO.

It may also be the nature of MetaSO... Rep seems to be more easy to come by here. Hell, I'm earning Rep twice as fast here as I am on SO.

Comment: oh yeah ?                       .

Comment: 14 questions and 152 Answers on SO versus 15 questions and 345 Answers on MSO.

Answer (score 3):

Probably a large part of it is due to the fact that he responds to feature-requests and bugs as the creator of the system - i.e. the guru / authority on it all.  It is a bit hard to argue with him when he says that e.g. voting *does* work the way it has been designed to work, etc.  Obviously, there are some things that people will disagree with and down vote him on, but since the up-votes are worth so much more, he will likely come out ahead in the end.

Answer (score 2):

If Jeff didn't delete all the Meta discussion on SO after the private beta, he would probably be number two behind Jon Skeet on SO.

Comment: I would actually like to see a bunch of that migrated here so we have a searchable record of it.

Comment: Can't you migrate them, Kyle? Or are they not just deleted, but erased from the system?

Answer (score 1):

It is funny, though.  If you look at his rep, there are *a lot* of down votes.  I guess some people have issues with authority.

Comment: And some people don't agree with everything he says. Just because he is the final authority on how things work does not mean that you have to believe everything he says like Gospel when it comes to his ideas towards future development. It is healthy to disagree so that the best solutions can be put forward.

Comment: We should erase the *by design* tag. It's his ultimate weapon.